# Visual Studio 2010 JavaScript Intellisense capitalizing the F in "function"

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I'm experiencing something recently that is really annoying and I can't figure out why it's doing it.  Not sure when it started, because I recently wiped my machine, so maybe its a recent update or maybe it's from a while ago.

Either way, here is what's happening.  When I'm declaring an anonymous function inline and start typing the "function() { ... }" part, the VS2010 intellisense comes up and replaces my lowercase function with its own capitalized "Function."  I guess this is some static function in JavaScript or JScript or something else, but I dont know.  Either way, its when I type the "()" that it assumes thats what I want.

If I'm declaring a standalone function it isn't affected because I don't put the "()" after that, so it just leaves what I type.

Here are some screen shots of what is happening.
[image: javascript intellisense][image]

It is quite frustrating because I don't notice it each time and then, of course, the function doesn't execute.  I also work in VS2008 each day and in 2008, both the "function" and "Function" are listed in the intellisense menu, but it defaults to the lowercase one so it doesn't affect me.

Is there any way I can override the intellisense settings?  Find a file and remove the "Function" one from the list because I'll never use it?  Make it default back to the lowercase "function" choice?

Any help would be great.  Thanks!

-Jorin

Comment: +1 This is extremely annoying (even though it's by design)

Comment: @SLaks - By design? `Function` is the `function` constructor, and is rarely used (and indeed should be used only rarely). If someone decided that it should be the default, they didn't really know what they were doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've nearly come to the conclusion that it's more productive to disable Visual Studio's Intellisense in JavaScript files.  However, if you do like most aspects of it, the "Statement completion" option is one way to remedy the particular problem of it replacing `function` with `Function` when you hit space:

[image]

**Update:**

I think VS2010's new paren spacing must have abused me into unconsciously typing things like this (note the space between function and parens):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

});
```

When you do that, it doesn't insert the Intellisense completion of `Function`.

With VS2010 sp1, they added back an option to format the parens without a space.  So, when I type the closing `});`, it formats the paren spacing back to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

... which is what I wanted to begin with.

Convoluted at first, but it becomes muscle memory pretty quickly.

Comment: Interestingly, I actually have that option selected.  Apparently even though it says "only tab or enter" it apparently means "only tab or enter or typing parentheses." :-)  Yeah, I really don't want to disable intellisense completely because some of these projects have a TON of functions and it's nice for finding those, but not much else...

Comment: I was apparently circumventing the paren-triggered completion through something else I hadn't noticed.  Updated the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll just have to get in the habit of typing that space.  Very unfortunate.  I was hoping someone would know a way to edit the intellisense files or whatever...

Comment: It turns out that this was a problem introduced by the JScript Editor Extensions at some point.  There's a new update today that fixes it: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/872d27ee-38c7-4a97-98dc-0d8a431cc2ed

Comment: Woohoo! That update fixed it.  Now the "function" snippet is the default.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be caused by Resharper, at least in Visual Studio 2013.  The extension is adding the DHtml.js file that includes "Function".  (For any other plugin, this would be sufficient cause for me to uninstall it.  Good thing it does so many other things right.)  See this question: [Javascript Intellisense list too long...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20395850/javascript-intellisense-list-in-vs-2013-for-a-custom-script-too-long-how-to-sup)

**Edit**:  JetBrains is fixing this bug:  (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-400812 ). In the meantime...

Resharper's options allow you to disable its intellisense augmentations by language.  To solve the problem, you can disable javascript from being affected, like so:

[image]

Comment: Whilst it's true that Resharper introduces this problem, the suggested solution kills automatic intellisense in the languages you don't select. You can get native intellisense by Ctrl-Spacing though...

Comment: @Steve it sure does.  IMO, intellisenseless javascript is preferrable to javascript that breaks itself as you type it.  Let's all look forward to the release that contains that bugfix, so it's no longer a decision of least-crappy alternative.

Comment: I'm lazy, I likes my Intellisense :)